# How can I make Notepad++ remember all instances of itself from last session?

Tags: windows, notepad++

When working with multiple instances of Notepad++, each with its own set of files opened, and the OS crashes then Notepad++ seems to be only remembering one single instance and not the rest.

Is there any way to instruct it, perhaps with a plugin, to remember all opened files of all instances so that in case of a crash they can all be recovered and not just a single window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at notepad++ Session management:

> Sessions are a set of files opened in Notepad++. They store the open files, the active file (and which view, see the section about Multi-View), the current selection and position in the file, the current bookmarks (see Bookmarks) and the current language (see the section about Languages). Using sessions, you can open a set of (related) files with one action.

You would have to manually save your sessions at regular intervals or use some kind of macro to automate this ... unless you install the Session Manager plugin

The [Session Manager Plugin](http://mfoster.com/npp/SessionMgr.html) adds aditional features such as Auto Save to the built in Session Manager

Comment: Not exactly the "plug and play" I wish it were (multiple instances have to be saved manually, auto-load can only remember one window), but still an improvement over nothing, thank you internet stranger :)

Comment: One more point on Notepad++ sessions - you can set a file extension for sessions, so that double-clicking the icon automatically opens the session in Notepad++.
Go to Preferences -> MISC -> Session file ext (bottom right corner). Something like "NPPSESS" shouldn't interefere with other file extensions. Then make sure you save your session(s) with the "NPPSESS" extension.

Comment: As far as I can see in 2022,  Session Manager Plugin discontinued in 2015, but there are 9 forks at Github. Can you tell us, which one is an actual one for now or may be there are other options|plugins created for the time being?

Comment: @WebComer It's built in the the latest Notepad++ see settings > preferences > backup

Comment: @DavidPostill
Thanks, it is a great info!
So by now all multisession mechanics is out-of-the-box? We just choose  settings > preferences > multi-instance> Always in multi-instance mode and voilà?

Comment: @WebComer Haven't tried that. I always use a single instance.